# Why importing an AAR goes over the 65k DEX limit while using a module does not?

Tags: android, gradle, dex, aar

I'm having a strange issue with dx, I'm trying to build a Gradle project that contains an android-library module insight and this works perfectly, DEX methods are around 58k.

If I take the compiled AAR from that library module and I place it in the project (aars folder) and I include it like this in gradle:

```
repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'library-aar-name', ext:'aar')
}
```

And obviously I remove the other project and clean, doing this will go over the 64k limit.

I'm importing only the -release aar, do you know what could cause this?

Comment: Is it possible when you setup the lib as a module, that it includes a proguard step that isn't included in the aar output step?

Comment: No differences with proguard. I will add that with a new project, using a module or an aar makes no difference in the method count. With this project instead, (Enabling multidexing) I discovered that with the AAR around 9000 methods are added while with the Module just 1500.

Comment: I haven't looked too much into it but the aar from my understanding is jsut another type of jar or zip. It just has a few more directories in it. So this is all before any dex file creation. In my mind you should be able to see the class files side by side and judge accordingly. My only idea would be that the dependencies of the aar are not removed/deduped since it's essentially a binary. Possibly a bug but I have no verified or looked into it much